# PHP - Copy ONLY if the file does not exist

Tags: php, file-handling

I have read dozens of similar questions but none of the answers were what I needed. Please point me to it if it exists.

I have a folder named "txts" and another folder named "content" like this:

```
files/texts    files/content
```

I want to copy a file from "txts" to "contents" but only if that file does not already exist in the "content" folder.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php 
 copy('files/txts/file1.txt', 'files/content/file1.txt');
?>
```

The problem is that it gets overwritten if it is already there. I need to copy the file (without deleting the original) and add it to the destination folder if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: if `!file_exists()`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `file_exists()` function.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
if (!file_exists($dest_loc)){
    copy($source_loc, $desk_loc);
}
```

Comment: Great! Not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php):

```
if(!file_exists('files/content/file1.txt')){
    copy('files/txts/file1.txt', 'files/content/file1.txt');
}else{
    echo "file already exists";
}
```

Comment: this seems like basically the same answer as above but it kept throwing me an error of an extra '}' ... You were correct that it was `!file_exists` though

Comment: This one forgot a closing parenthesis in the if statement.